# Tomcat server is not detecting JARs

Tags: java, tomcat

I am running a Tomcat server for my project. I kept my required JARs in `ROOT/WEB-INF/classes`.
But when I start my server and send some requests, I am getting `classNotFoundException`s. Although, when I tried extracting those JARs and kept it as a directory in the same path, I'm getting expected responses.

What might be wrong, or is this the way it actually works ?

Comment: Maybe those archives are meant to be put somewhere else and the server to extract them to the directory you mention.

Answer (score 0):

JAR files should be located in `WEB-INF/lib` not `WEB-INF/classes` which is for classes and other resources not packed in a JAR file.

In your case the correct location for those JAR files is `ROOT/WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It worked